# HTML5 - JavaScript - Load Text Files to Radio Button and then Read Text File for Radio Button Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the file input with 'multiple' enabled to select several text files and then load their values (names) into radio buttons.  Then on selecting the radio button and hitting "GO" it will show the contents of the text file.

Basically several text files are chosen, when the radio button is selected and GO is pressed it displays the contents on the screen.  I am very stuck  Here is what I have.  Please forgive me as I am guessing I am way off but I am a beginner.

Also, is there a way to use a LOCAL file location (like C:\myfile.txt) versus having to select with the input=file command?  I would like to try both.  This is not used online, the local file is actually local on the machine where the html is loaded but I understand this part may be impossible.

```js
updateList = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('file');
  var output = document.getElementById('fileList');


  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
    output.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" value="' + input.files.item(i).name + '" id="place">';
  }

}



function Go() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('place');
  var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
      }

      reader.readAsText(file);
    } else {
      fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple onchange="updateList();" />
<br/>Selected files:

<div id="fileDisplayArea"></div>
<div id="fileList"></div>
<button id="button" onclick="Go();">GO</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes just for clarity.  I got rid of inline javascript and instead used event listeners.  Changed the value of each radio button to its index so we could use it when we're looking through the file list to find out which one is selected.  Removed the ID from the radio buttons because you shouldn't use the same ID on multiple elements.  Added a label to each input that shows the file name.  Put a `name` attribute on the radio buttons so only one is selected at a time.

Your main issue was that in your `Go` function you were using the radio inputs as the `fileInput` variable and you were setting a change event on those radio inputs which didn't make sense since you were calling the `Go` function on button click.

As far as I know you can't use a local path due to security.  Imagine if any JavaScript could just pickup files from your computer without you explicitly choosing one.

```js
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  // this refers to the input.  could also use e.target;
  var input = this;
  var output = document.getElementById("fileList");

  // just using the index for the value of each radio button
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
    output.innerHTML +=
      '<label><input type="radio" value="' + i + '" class="place" name="files">' + input.files.item(i).name +
      "</label><br/>";
  }
});

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var textType = /text.*/;
  var fileInput = document.getElementById("file");
  var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById("fileDisplayArea");
  
  // here we're finding the checked radio button and getting its value
  // to use below as the index in our file list
  var selectedRadioIndex = parseInt(
    document.querySelector('input[name="files"]:checked').value
  );

  if (fileInput.files[selectedRadioIndex].type.match(textType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[selectedRadioIndex]);
  } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText =
      fileInput.files[selectedRadioIndex].name + " is not supported!";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/>
<br/>Selected files:

<div id="fileDisplayArea"></div><div id="fileList"></div>
<button id="button">GO</button>
```